# Using excel sheets for python

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm new to using this kind of program. You see I'm trying to run a series of commands 
in python (which were previously written) with the information of some excel sheets, for this the following error was found in my commands:

```
if food_groups[measure]['constraints_serves'][p_strip][minormax] != f:

KeyError: 'constraints_serves'
```

What does it mean? 
Any response, I would appreciate it.

This is a part of the excel spreadsheet that I'm having problems with (the error its found at the end)

```
for row in nutrientsTargetsHSheet:
  p = row['Healthy diet per day']
  p_strip = p.replace('aduilt', 'adult').replace(' min', '').replace(' max', '').replace('woman', 'women')
  n = nutrient_targets.get(p_strip, {})
  if 'min' in p:
    minormax = 'min'
  elif 'max' in p:
    minormax = 'max'

  for measure, value in row.items():
    if 'grams' in measure and measure != 'fibre grams':
      continue
    try:
      if value == "max":
        value = 100
      f = float(value)
      if '(s)' in measure:
        measure = measure.replace("vege", "Vegetables").replace(" (s)", "").capitalize()
        if food_groups[measure]['constraints_serves'][p_strip][minormax] != f:
          logger.warning("Override {} {} for {} from {} to {}".format(measure, minormax, p_strip, food_groups[measure]['constraints_serves'][p_strip][minormax], f))
          food_groups[measure]['constraints_serves'][p_strip][minormax] = f
```

Comment: I highly recommend you try using Pandas dataframes. This function here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) turns excel files into a dataframe, which is a much easier thing to work with. You got a KeyError because the format of your data is complicated to navigate, and a mistake was made.

Answer (score 0):

The error means it cannot find the key 'constraints_servers'.
This could be because it does not exist, perhaps it is named wrong.

However from what I can see it seems you are calling it against food_groups where you mean to call it against measure. Try replacing the line with:

```
if measure['constraints_serves'][p_strip][minormax] != f:
```